# How to pass variable as parameter to ado.NET Source via expression

Tags: database, ssis, continuous-integration, integration, ssis-2012

In SSIS User::variable Datetime to ADO.NET Source, the variable name is evaluated in expression instead of passing the value from the variable. Please let me know how to handle this.

I was expecting to get the value from the variable which is passed inside the ado.net souce while evaluating